# A program / site paste some xml, submit some sort of xpath query and return a result

Tags: web-apps, xml

I am on a project where there's lots of XML files that I have to configure.

I am on a computer where I cannot install anything which is why a web solution is best. So I just want to find something on the web that simply allows me to paste in an xml file, then put in a xquery (or some other xml querying language) and return me the result.

Comment: Can you provide more details to help others help you?

Comment: An example might be useful here. As phrased currently, it's a bit vague.

Comment: The sites listed in the answer is exactly what i'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two online tools

[XPATH Tester/Evaluator/Query](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php)

[XPath Tester / Evaluator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Both let you input the XML, than run your XPATH query on them.