# XPath GUI for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, xml, xpath

I'm looking for an application where I can load an XML file and inspect different values with an XPath location.

Similar to this question on [A program / site paste some xml, submit some sort of xpath query and return a result](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17850/5049), but I have the opposite restriction.  I can install things and work with sensitive information so I need a client based program that *doesn't* run on the web.

I've heard good things about [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xpath.html), but I was looking for something free with fewer bells and whistles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XMLQuire's XPath Editor](http://qutoric.com/sketchpath/xpath-editor.html) is
 free and does the job well, or at least it did the last time I tried it.

Comment: As author of XMLQuire, I'm planning to retire this in mid 2021. This will be replaced by  the [Visual Studio Code XPath 3.1 Notebook](https://github.com/pgfearo/vscode-nodebook) extension - currently a Work in Progress

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), which already comes with an XML editor, a DTD, and Schema validator. Additionally, you can enable the XPath window that allows you to enter an XPath expression and get the different results instantly. You can extend the usage by installing other plugins from the Eclipse Market.

Another free software is [Editix 2008](http://free.editix.com/release.html).

I already worked with both, so try them to get your own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.8.8.html) with XML Tools plugin.