# XPath online tester with save & share feature

Tags: web-apps, hosted, xpath

I am looking for an XPath 2.0+ online checker not only for testing but also for saving and sharing - similar to online regex tester (like regex101.com) or online compiler sites (like ideone.com, rextester.com).

The idea here is to be able to have shareable samples, e.g. for Stack Overflow questions.

I found some XPath online checker, e.g. here [A program / site paste some xml, submit some sort of xpath query and return a result](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17850/a-program-site-paste-some-xml-submit-some-sort-of-xpath-query-and-return-a-re), but none of them is shareable.

Answer (score 1):

So far I found three sites:

#### XPath Online Checker (shareable)

- [videlibri](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi): Template / XPath 3.0 / XQuery 3.0 / CSS 3 Selector / JSONiq Online Tester
- [XPath Evaluator](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/): Online XPath tester that supports XPath 3.0 and XQuery 3.0 via Saxon-HE 9.7 and XPath 1.0 via .NET XPath engine ([GitHub](https://github.com/har07/XPathEval)).
- [BeautifyConverter XPath Tester](https://www.beautifyconverter.com/xpath-tester.php) (requires free registration, sports many other useful online tools like minifiers, beautifiers, converters, validators, etc.)

<sup>(not necessarily the best, so please feel free to add more/better sites & resources)</sup>

I don't know how long the links are retained or any other caveats. 
The first two sites do not require registration. I like the first one best, however, the permalinks are kinda long and ugly.